# How is a Tor relay's advertised bandwidth verified?

Tags: relays, directory, bandwidth, relay-adversary

Back in 2007, Bauer et al. showed that a relay-level adversary could lie about their bandwidth capabilities, thus unfairly increasing the chance of having their relay selected in Tor circuits [^1].

Today, this vulnerability is fixed. How? Do directory authorities verify a relay's advertised bandwidth, and/or do clients? Or has the bandwidth advertisement mechanism been removed such that *only* directories/clients measure it?

[^1]: Bauer, Kevin, et al. "Low-resource routing attacks against Tor." Proceedings of the 2007 ACM workshop on Privacy in electronic society. ACM, 2007.

Comment: @JSEvans I'm not sure this is a helpful comment. Is the purpose of this StackExchange site not to answer questions *without* requiring people to go through the extremely extensive Tor wiki, tracker, and literature? I did in fact search through the documentation, but quickly ran into the issue that it's difficult to grok without already being in the know.

Comment: 2 Things.  First I deleted the previous command. I admit that it was not sufficiently helpful. That is why it was a comment and not an answer.  Secondly, you *are* expected to have done your own research before asking. In reality, nobody does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [Top changes in Tor since the 2004 design paper (Part 2)](https://blog.torproject.org/top-changes-tor-2004-design-paper-part-2)

> Bandwidth Authorities
>
> Of course, once you choose nodes with unequal
> probability, you open the possibility of an attacker trying to see a
> disproportionate number of circuits -- not by running an extra-high
> number of nodes -- but by claiming to have a very large bandwidth.
>
> For a while, we tried to limit the impact of this attack by limiting
> the maximum bandwidth that a client would believe, so that a single
> rogue node couldn't just claim to have infinite bandwidth.
>
> In 0.2.1.17-rc, clients switched from using bandwidth values
> advertised by nodes themselves to using values published in the
> network status consensus document. A subset of the authorities measure
> and vote on nodes' observed bandwidth, to prevent misbehaving nodes
> from claiming (intentionally or accidentally) to have too much
> capacity.